# Error al recuperar datos desde php por json

Tags: php, ajax, json, php7

tengo un problemilla, estoy enviando una serie de datos a un php el cual me hace una consulta en  una sql y me devuelve el array por json para ponerlo en el html despues ( en una tabla ), pero el problema es que solo me recupera una fila, cuando almenos hay 2 en mi base de datos que cumplen los requisitos.

en la consola tampoco me sale, mas que 1 resultado, a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.
//Este es el ajax que envia los datos

```html
            var url = "buscador.php";
        $.ajax({                        
type: "POST",                 
url: url,  
dataType:'JSON',         
data: {competicion:competicion, temporada:temporada, fase:fase, grupo:grupo, jornada:jornada, action:'resultados'}, 


});
```

```
//este es el php
 $futbol->query = "
    SELECT * FROM competiciones where competicion = '".$_POST["competicion"]."' and fase = '".$_POST["fase"]."' and temporada = '".$_POST["temporada"]."' and grupo = '".$_POST["grupo"]."' and jornada = '".$_POST["jornada"]."' ORDER BY id ASC
    ";
    
    $result2 = $futbol->get_result();
    
    $futbol->execute();
    
    $jornadas = $futbol->row_count();


    $data = array();
    foreach($result2 as $row){
        $data['local'] = $row['local'];
        $data['resultadolocal'] = $row['resultadolocal'];
        $data['resultadovisitante'] = $row['resultadovisitante'];
        $data['visitante'] = $row['visitante'];
        $data['estadio'] = $row['estadio'];
        $data['fechapartido'] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["fechapartido"]));
        $data['horapartido'] = $row['horapartido'];
        $data['boton_ficha'] = '<button type="button" name="ficha_estadio" class="bg-danger text-white" data-id="'.$row["estadio"].'">ESTADIO</button>';
        $data['boton_acta'] = '<button type="button" name="ficha_acta" class="bg-danger text-white" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">ACTA</button>';            
        
        }
        echo json_encode($data);   
        
        

       
        


       
}
```

// Y este es el ajax que me los muestra

```html
success: function(data)             
{ 
    $('#tabla_resultados').show();
    $('#visitante').html(data.visitante);
    $('#local').html(data.local);
    if (data.resultadolocal < data.resultadovisitante) {
        $('#resultado').html('<div class="row"><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorrojo"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>');

    }
    if (data.resultadolocal < data.resultadovisitante) {

        $('#resultado').html('<div class="row"><div class="marcadorrojo"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>');

    }
    if (data.resultadolocal = data.resultadovisitante) {

    $('#resultado').html('<div class="row"><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data.resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>');

}


    $('#cuando').html('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="far fa-map"></i> '+data.estadio+'</div><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> '+data.fechapartido+'</div><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> '+data.horapartido+'</div></div>');

    $('#info').html('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">'+data.boton_ficha+'</div>&nbsp;<div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">'+data.boton_acta+'</div></div>');   
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás creando un arreglo `$data` y en cada iteración sobrescribes las propiedades. Debes agregar un nuevo elemento por cada fila:

```
$data = []; // Es lo mismo que $data = array();
foreach($result2 as $row) {
    // Agregar elemento en lugar de sobrescribir propiedades
    $data[] = [
        'local' => $row['local'],
        'resultadolocal' => $row['resultadolocal'],
        // Aquí agrega las que faltan
        'boton_acta' => '<button type="button" name="ficha_acta" class="bg-danger text-white" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">ACTA</button>'
    ];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente pude hacerlo con un bucle for, recorriendo el array, dejo aqui el codigo por si a alguien le pudiera servir.

Un saludo

```html
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    if (data[i].resultadolocal < data[i].resultadovisitante) {
        var resultado = '<div class="row"><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorrojo"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>';

    }
    
    if (data[i].resultadolocal > data[i].resultadovisitante) {

        var resultado = '<div class="row"><div class="marcadorrojo"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>';

    }
    if (data[i].resultadolocal = data[i].resultadovisitante) {

        var resultado = '<div class="row"><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadovisitante+'</div></div><div class="marcadorblanco"></div><div class="marcadorverde"><div class="marcador">'+data[i].resultadolocal+'</div></div></div>';

    }
    var ubifechahora = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="far fa-map"></i> '+data[i].estadio+'</div><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> '+data[i].fechapartido+'</div><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i> '+data[i].horapartido+'</div></div>';
    
    var info = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">'+data[i].boton_ficha+'</div>&nbsp;<div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">'+data[i].boton_acta+'</div></div>';

$("#clasificacion").append('<tr class="table-xl"><th scope="col">'+data[i].visitante+'</th><th scope="col">'+resultado+'</th><th scope="col">'+data[i].local+'</th><th scope="col">'+ubifechahora+'</th><th scope="col">'+info+'</th></tr>');
    }
```

Comment: Es no es una respuesta, mejor edita tu pregunta y añade lo que has intentado y explicando que error tuviste al implementar la solución

Comment: exactamente puse lo que me propusieron, pero al hacer la consulta ahora, me devuelve todo como undefined, es decir no devuelve correctamente el json o no lo decodifica.
por eso puse el ajax que estoy usando, quizas tambien haya que modificar algo ahi, antes si que me funcionaba, pero decidi hacerlo de esta otra forma por un problema que tendria en el futuro

Comment: Por eso te digo que edites tu pregunta añadiendo esto, para que así otros que la vean sepan que has intentado y puedan resolver el error, de lo contrario obtendrás la misma respuesta

Comment: ya lo consegui, finalmente utilice un bucle for para ir recorriendo el array y pintando los TD y TR con cada resultado

Comment: También puedes responder a tu propia pregunta para que, si otra persona tiwnw el problema, pueda resolverlo

Comment: bueno puse el codigo resultante igualmente, por si le sirve a alguien